# How to making live clock in single line console log format in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

In browser, we can making the live clock in single line display by using setInterval and replacing content inside HTML element like this:

```js
var span = document.getElementById('span');

    function time() {
      var d = new Date();
      var s = d.getSeconds();
      var m = d.getMinutes();
      var h = d.getHours();
      span.textContent = 
        ("0" + h).substr(-2) + ":" + ("0" + m).substr(-2) + ":" + ("0" + s).substr(-2);
    }
setInterval(time, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="span"></span>
```

But, how we can do it the same thing in terminal console with NodeJS? If we use console.log and setInterval it will create new line. Like this:

```
07:00:01
07:00:02
07:00:03
07:00:04
```

I just want to display console.log live clock in single line on terminal.

Comment: @jarmod No, still need example code to display live clock in single line console.log terminal .. Which is need forever loop implementation like setInterval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You w ant to use `\r` to terminate the previous line with stdout.

```
    setInterval(() => process.stdout.write(`${new Date()}\r`), 1000);
```